# vimscript: Get visual mode selection text in mapping

Tags: vim

So I'm trying to have a binding that runs `lvimgrep` on the currently selected text.

```
  fun! s:get_visual_selection()
       let l=getline("'<")
       let [line1,col1] = getpos("'<")[1:2]
       let [line2,col2] = getpos("'>")[1:2]
       return l[col1 - 1: col2 - 1]
 endfun

 vnoremap <expr> <script><leader>* ":lvimgrep /" .  <SID>get_visual_selection()  . "/j **/*." .  expand("%:e") . " \|lopen"
```

The function's from the comment on the question: [How to get visually selected text in VimScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533565/how-to-get-visually-selected-text-in-vimscript)

Thing is that it is behaving really weird: Most of the times the text returned by the function doesn't match the visual selection and more often than not, it is the text of the last visual selection - not the current one.

Have gone through tons of posts around getting visual selection text in vimscript but can't get it to work.

I have also tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/1534347/287085 without success (copying selection to register) - get an error when called from my binding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `'<,'>` marks are not set until **after** the current selection has been left (either by executing a command on it, or through `<Esc>`). Here, your *expression mapping* makes it more complex to prepend an `<Esc>` to leave visual mode first, so it's easier to insert the expression with `:help i_CTRL-R` and the expression register `=`:

```
:vnoremap <script> <leader>* <Esc>:lvimgrep /<C-R><C-R>=<SID>get_visual_selection()<CR>/j **/*.<C-R><C-R>=expand("%:e")<CR>\|lopen
```

If you don't mind clobbering the default register, you could also just *yank* the selection:

```
:vnoremap <leader>* y:lvimgrep /<C-R><C-R>"/j **/*.<C-R><C-R>=expand("%:e")<CR>\|lopen
```

Comment: that's the second vimscript mystery you've solved for me in a day... :) thanks!

Comment: @Raghu: Glad I could help. Your questions are well formulated and clear... keep going!

Comment: Nice, but could you factor out the "get visual selection" part from the other part, for clarity? And what does `expand("%:e")` mean?