# Vim obtain string between visual selection range with Python

Tags: python, vim

```
Here is some text
here is line two of text
```

I visually select from `is` to `is` in Vim: (brackets represent the visual selection `[` `]`)

```
Here [is some text
here is] line two of text
```

Using Python, I can obtain the range tuples of the selection:

```
function! GetRange()
python << EOF

import vim

buf   = vim.current.buffer # the buffer
start = buf.mark('<')      # start selection tuple: (1,5)
end   = buf.mark('>')      # end selection tuple: (2,7)

EOF
endfunction
```

I source this file: `:so %`, select the text visually, run `:<,'>call GetRange()` and

now that I have `(1,5)` and `(2,7)`. In Python, how can I compile the string that is the following:

`is some text\nhere is`

Would be nice to:

1. Obtain this string for future manipulation
2. then replace this selected range with the updated/manipulated string

Comment: Is it necessary to do this in python? I left a vimscript only answer below. Rereading the question I'm not sure if this will be acceptable for you but I'm going to leave it there for now.

Comment: Many helpful answers in Vim script at [How to get visually selected text in VimScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1533565).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
fun! GetRange()
python << EOF

import vim

buf = vim.current.buffer
(lnum1, col1) = buf.mark('<')
(lnum2, col2) = buf.mark('>')
lines = vim.eval('getline({}, {})'.format(lnum1, lnum2))
lines[0] = lines[0][col1:]
lines[-1] = lines[-1][:col2]
print "\n".join(lines)

EOF
endfun
```

You can use `vim.eval` to get python values of vim functions and variables.

Comment: I think `line[-1][:col2+1]` would be more convenient.

Comment: iiuc this assumes that the visual marked range spans more than one line. If lnum1=lnum2, then in the replacement `lines[-1] = lines[-1][:col2]` `col2` does not cut at the original column. (see Andrew Magee's patch below).

Answer (score 4):

This would probably work if you used pure vimscript

```
function! GetRange()
    let @" = substitute(@", '\n', '\\n', 'g')
endfunction

vnoremap ,r y:call GetRange()<CR>gvp
```

This will convert all newlines into `\n` in the visual selection and replace the selection with that string.

This mapping yanks the selection into the `"` register. Calls the function (isn't really necessary since its only one command). Then uses `gv` to reselect the visual selection and then pastes the quote register back onto the selected region.

Note: in vimscript all user defined functions must start with an Uppercase letter.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another version based on Conner's answer. I took qed's suggestion and also added a fix for when the selection is entirely within one line.

```
import vim

def GetRange():
    buf = vim.current.buffer
    (lnum1, col1) = buf.mark('<')
    (lnum2, col2) = buf.mark('>')
    lines = vim.eval('getline({}, {})'.format(lnum1, lnum2))
    if len(lines) == 1:
        lines[0] = lines[0][col1:col2 + 1]
    else:
        lines[0] = lines[0][col1:]
        lines[-1] = lines[-1][:col2 + 1]
    return "\n".join(lines)
```

Comment: What if text are selected in **visual block** mode? The function doesn't appear to get it right.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me.. what is it doing for you?