# Getting Syntax Highlighted Keywords in Vim

Tags: vim

I'm trying to write a simple vim script for learning purpose. What I would like to do is capitalizing all syntaxt higlighted keywords in a text like below.

```
select column_name(s)
FROM table1
inner join table2
on table1.column_name=table2.column_name;
```

To

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name;
```

And of course I can do it via regex search and replace but I want it to be automatic based on currently used syntaxt file in vim. I don't want to hardcode all keywords again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533565/how-to-get-visually-selected-text-in-vimscript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried vimscript yet, but here are what I combine from few posts:

```
function! CapKeywords()
    redir => lst
    syntax list sqlKeyword sqlStatement
    redir END
    for i in split(lst)
        :exe '%s/\<' . i . '\>/' . toupper(i) . '/gce'
    endfor
endfunction

nnoremap <leader>h :call CapKeywords()<CR>
```

Works on `select` and `on` from your example. I don't know where are `inner` and `join` sits, so I leave it to you. Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried your script and it's working. The thing I didn't like, it shows  syntax group as output and asks me for every keyword to replace it or not. I'm trying to fix these issues.

Comment: To disable confirming each substitution you need to remove flag `c` from '/gce'. As of syntax group - I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: To disable output I have changed command to "silent syntax list sqlStatement"