# How to pass a vim visual selection to commandline in Windows

Tags: windows, vim

I've been trying to use the offline document program zeal with Vim in Windows.
I got the following line to open a zeal window in normal mode with the word under the cursor.

```
nnoremap gz :sil !start "f:\download\zeal-20140620\zeal.exe" --query "<cword>"<CR>
```

But I was wondering if there was an equivalent way to do this from visual mode, (i.e. create a mapping to pass the selected text in visual mode to zeal as a complete string in double quotes)

I tried looking in Vimhelp under visual mode, !!, escaping, and cword, but didn't see anything that quite fit what I wanted to do in a regular non-cygwin windows 7 environment.

Here are a couple unsuccessful attempts:

```
vnoremap gz :sil !start "f:\download\zeal-20140620\zeal.exe" --query "!!"<CR>

vnoremap gz :sil !start "f:\download\zeal-20140620\zeal.exe" --query "'<'>"<CR>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533565/how-to-get-visually-selected-text-in-vimscript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind clobbering a register, it's easiest to first *yank* the visual selection, and then insert the register contents into the command-line via `:execute`:

```
:vnoremap gz y:exe 'sil !start "f:\download\zeal-20140620\zeal.exe" --query ' . shellescape(@@, 1)<CR>
```

For more elaborate approaches that don't override a register, see [how to get visually selected text in vimscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533565/how-to-get-visually-selected-text-in-vimscript).

Comment: Sorry I was so slow about getting back on this.  This was just what I was looking for.  Thanks Ingo!