# Running blocks of code inside vim

Tags: python, vim

I recently added the following code in the .vimrc:

```
" Runs python inside vim
  autocmd FileType python nnoremap <buffer> <F9> :exec '!clear; python' shellescape(@%, 1)<cr>
```

which allows me to run the entire python script from inside vim when pressed the F9 key. Nevertheless, several times I do not want to run the entire python script but just one line or even a block of lines. I googled    in searching for these behavior but could not find any solution that worked, at least for me.

Someone can help me on this?

Thanks

Comment: Something like [vim-quickrun](https://github.com/thinca/vim-quickrun) should do nicely for this. ([README](https://github.com/thinca/vim-quickrun/blob/master/doc/quickrun.txt)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should make a function to get your visually selected text. I brought it from https://stackoverflow.com/a/6271254/3108885:

```
function! s:GetVisualSelection()
  let [lnum1, col1] = getpos("'<")[1:2]
  let [lnum2, col2] = getpos("'>")[1:2]
  let lines = getline(lnum1, lnum2)
  let lines[-1] = lines[-1][:col2 - (&selection == 'inclusive' ? 1 : 2)]
  let lines[0] = lines[0][col1 - 1:]
  return join(lines, "\n")
endfunction
```

Then, add an `autocmd` for Visual mode.

```
autocmd FileType python vnoremap <buffer> <F9> :<C-U>exec '!clear; python -c' shellescape(<SID>GetVisualSelection(), 1)<CR>
```

Note that `<C-U>` is for cleaning `'<,'>` things when `:` is pressed on Visual mode. Also we use `python -c` to pass a program as a string.