# vim: send text-selection to bash

Tags: linux, vim

How can I send the currently selected (in visual mode) text content to a bash command?

I know, bash commands can be called with `:!`, but for the rest I don't find documentation.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can get visually selected text by a function. I brought this from https://stackoverflow.com/a/6271254/3108885:

```
function! s:GetVisualSelection()
  let [lnum1, col1] = getpos("'<")[1:2]
  let [lnum2, col2] = getpos("'>")[1:2]
  let lines = getline(lnum1, lnum2)
  let lines[-1] = lines[-1][:col2 - (&selection == 'inclusive' ? 1 : 2)]
  let lines[0] = lines[0][col1 - 1:]
  return join(lines, "\n")
endfunction
```

Then add a map for Visual mode:

```
vnoremap <buffer> <F5> :<C-U>exec '!python -c' shellescape(<SID>GetVisualSelection(), 1)<CR>
```

If you press <kbd>F5</kbd>, visually selected python code will be executed. You may define this map only for Python code, by prepending `autocmd FileType python` before `vnoremap`. So multiple file types can be handled.

```
autocmd FileType python vnoremap <buffer> <F5> :<C-U>exec '!python -c' shellescape(<SID>GetVisualSelection(), 1)<CR>
autocmd FileType ruby vnoremap <buffer> <F5> :<C-U>exec '!ruby -e' shellescape(<SID>GetVisualSelection(), 1)<CR>
```