# How to map vim visual mode to replace my selected text parts?

Tags: dictionary, select, vim, replace, mode

I wish to replace part of my words, as selected by visual mode. E.g.:

I've got a simple text file:

```
------------------
hello there hehe
She's not here
------------------
```

I need to change all "he" into "her".

What I wish to do is not to type `%s` command, but under visual mode:

1. `v` to select "he"
2. Press some hot key, and vim prompts me to input the new text
3. I type the new text, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, done.

I guess we can do it with vmap? But how to achieve it? Thanks!

Comment: What about macros ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the solution all credits go to User @[xolox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/788200/xolox) from his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6271254/4392605) which I developed to get the required task:

```
vnoremap ; :call Get_visual_selection()<cr>


function! Get_visual_selection()
  " Why is this not a built-in Vim script function?!
  let [lnum1, col1] = getpos("'<")[1:2]
  let [lnum2, col2] = getpos("'>")[1:2]
  let lines = getline(lnum1, lnum2)
  let lines[-1] = lines[-1][: col2 - (&selection == 'inclusive' ? 1 : 2)] 
  let lines[0] = lines[0][col1 - 1:] 
  let selection = join(lines,'\n')
  let change = input('Change the selection with: ')
  execute ":%s/".selection."/".change."/g"
endfunction
```

You can change the mapping `;` to any hot key you want.

[image]

Comment: Brilliant answer, it solves me problem. Just curious how did you make the gif file and upload to stackoverflow? Any screen/type to git tool you used? Thanks.

Comment: You can check this [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85516/embed-image-in-stackoverflow) to know how to upload a gif in this site and in order to create one  you can do a screencast and then convert it to animated image.

Answer (score 2):

You can add this mapping:

```
vnoremap <F7> :s/he/&r/g<cr>
```

Then when you press `<F7>` in visual mode, vim will do the text substitution on selected lines.

Note that, the :s cmd in above mapping is just example, it replaces all `he` into `her`, no matter if `he` is a part of other word, E.g. `She's` -> `Sher's`

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
:vnoremap <F7> y:%s/<C-r><C-r>"//g<Left><Left>
```

This `y`anks the selected text, and then builds an (incomplete, with the cursor inside the replacement part) `:%s` command-line. You just need to fill in the replacement and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

#### Open issues

- Clobbers the default register. You can use the function from @[Meninx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4392605/meninx)'s answer, or `ingo#selection#Get()` from my [ingo-library plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4433).
- Uses the selected text as a regular expression pattern. To use as literal text, this needs escaping (also for any newlines in a multi-line selection). Again, I have a `ingo#regexp#EscapeLiteralText()` in my plugin.

Comment: Can't we avoid the yank by using `<C-r>*` as the search text? The `*` register appears to contain the latest visual selection. This works for me: `:vnoremap <F7> <Esc>:%s/<C-r>*//g<Left><Left>`

Comment: Answering my own question: The `*` register is [only available on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18031078/99777).

Answer (score 0):

I see you've already picked an answer that works for you, just wanted to also leave this plugin here: https://github.com/AndrewRadev/multichange.vim.

It does basically the same thing. Works on just words by default, allows you to select text to change in visual mode as well. It also has some some additional features, like printing how many substitutions were made off-screen.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a key binding for a combination of the leader key and the s key to achieve what you want.

With lua:

```lua
vim.keymap.set("x", "<leader>s", '"zy<Esc>:%s/<C-R>z//g<Left><Left>')
```

The same in Vimscript:

```
xnoremap <leader>s '"zy<Esc>:%s/<C-R>z//g<Left><Left>
```

This yanks the selection to the z registser, escapes visual mode and prepares a substitute command with the selection as the text to be substituted.

Use the following command to set your leader key, in this example to the space key:

With lua:

```lua
vim.g.mapleader = " "
```

With Vimscript:

```
let mapleader = " "
```