# vim: escaping strings for substitution (vimscript)

Tags: vim, escaping, substitution

I currently write a substitute function that I often need for programming in vim.

The functions I already wrote look like this and run basically okay for searching and replacing strings which do not have any special characters inside. I already realized to escape the "/" automatically. My question is, how do I have to adapt the escape() function in the line

```
execute ':silent :argdo %s/' . escape(searchPattern, '/') . '/' . escape(replacePattern, '/') . '/ge'
```

So that automatically all of the characters that have to be escaped will be escaped?

```
" MAIN FUNCTION
" inspired by http://vimcasts.org/episodes/project-wide-find-and-replace/
function! SubstituteProjectwide(searchInput)
  :set hidden
  let cwd = getcwd()
  let filename=expand('%:p')
  call inputsave()
  let searchPattern = input('Search for: ', a:searchInput)
  let replacePattern = input('Replace "' . searchPattern . '" with: ')
  let filePattern = input('Filepattern: ', cwd . '/**/*.*')
  call inputrestore()
  execute ':silent :args ' . filePattern
  execute ':silent :vimgrep /' . searchPattern . '/g ##'
  execute ':silent :Qargs'
  execute ':silent :argdo %s/' . escape(searchPattern, '/\') . '/' . escape(replacePattern, '/\') . '/ge'
  execute ':silent :edit ' . filename
  echo 'Replaced "' . searchPattern . '" with "' . replacePattern . '" in ' . filePattern
endfunction

" VISUAL ENTRYPOINT WITH SELECTED TEXT
function! SubstituteProjectwideVisual()
  let v = @*
  call SubstituteProjectwide(GetVisualSelectedText())
endfunction
:vnoremap <F6> :call SubstituteProjectwideVisual()<cr>

" NORMAL ENTRYPOINT WITH WORD UNDER CURSOR
function! SubstituteProjectwideNormal()
  let wordUnderCursor = expand("<cword>")
  call SubsituteProjectwide(wordUnderCursor)
endfunction
:nnoremap <F6> :call SubstituteProjectwideNormal()<cr>

" GETTING THE FILES W## Heading ##ICH CONTAIN SEARCH PATTERN
" copied from http://vimcasts.org/episodes/project-wide-find-and-replace/
command! -nargs=0 -bar Qargs execute 'args' QuickfixFilenames()
function! QuickfixFilenames()
  let buffer_numbers = {}
  for quickfix_item in getqflist()
    let buffer_numbers[quickfix_item['bufnr']] = bufname(quickfix_item['bufnr'])
  endfor
  return join(map(values(buffer_numbers), 'fnameescape(v:val)'))
endfunction

" GETTING THE CURRENT VISUAL SELECTION
" copied from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533565/how-to-get-visually-selected-text-in-vimscript
function! GetVisualSelectedText()
  let [line_start, column_start] = getpos("'<")[1:2]
  let [line_end, column_end] = getpos("'>")[1:2]
  let lines = getline(line_start, line_end)
  if len(lines) == 0
    return ''
  endif
  let lines[-1] = lines[-1][: column_end - (&selection == 'inclusive' ? 1 : 2)]
  let lines[0] = lines[0][column_start - 1:]
  return join(lines, "\n")
endfunction
```

UPDATE

I managed to escape many characters like that

```
escape(searchPattern, ' / \') . '/' . escape(replacePattern, ' / \')
```

But how do I know which list of characters I have to escape, when it is basically possible, that every character can be inside the search and also the replace string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do a **literal substitution**, specify "very-nomagic" (`:help /\V`) , and escape the separator (`/`) and `\`
in the source.

In the replacement, `&` and `~` must be escaped, too, if the `'magic'` option is set. (`\V` doesn't work here.)

```
execute ':silent :argdo %s/\V' . escape(searchPattern, '/\') . '/' . escape(replacePattern, '/\' . (&magic ? '&~' : '')) . '/ge'
```

Line breaks (if possible) must be changed from `^M` to `\n`:

```
execute ':silent :argdo %s/\V' . substitute(escape(searchPattern, '/\'),"\n",'\\n','ge') . '/' . escape(replacePattern, '/\' . (&magic ? '&~' : '')) . '/ge'
```

Comment: it seems to run. i have to test it with some more complex search terms

Comment: @divramod Remember that you also need to escape `&` and `~`, at least in the replacement pattern. See the end of the last line in @ingo-karkat's answer.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't exactly answer your question but is another way of looking at the problem you're trying to solve. I don't entirely follow what the `:args` setup is doing for you since the quickfix has all of the info you need after the `:vimgrep`.

I have this in my vimrc:

```
nnoremap <F3> :vimgrep // $PROJECT_ROOT_DIR/src/**/*.{cpp,h,c,inl,msg}<C-Left><C-Left><Right>
```

Obviously you'll want to customize the search path, as this focuses on just the above five file extensions in a specific file hierarchy that was configured each time I launched Vim...

Anyway, once you've got that, `:cr` makes sure you're at the beginning, then do the search&replace you want inside of a macro. You can actually test it out on the first few finds if you want, but then...

`qbq` Clear the 'b' register.

`qa` Start recording the 'a' macro'

`:%s/this/that/g` Start the macro and substitute 'that' for 'this'. (Press enter)

`:w|cnf` write the file and go to the next one (Press enter)

`q` Stop recording the 'a' macro.

Then `qb@a@bq` will run the macro once, saving it in `@b`. Then just run
(type) `@b` once more and it'll keep calling itself until it's done.