# Remove lines from buffer that match the selected text

Tags: regex, vim

When analyzing large log files, I often remove lines containing text I find irrelevant:

```
:g/whatever/d
```

Sometimes I find text that spans multiple lines, like stacktraces. For that, I record the steps taken (search, go to start anchor, delete to end anchor) and replay that macro with `100000@q`. I'm searching for a function or a feature vim already has included that allows me to mark text and remove all lines containing this text. Ideally this would also work for block selection.

Comment: so you are searching for a certain pattern, go back to a certain start anchor, and delete until a certain end anchor?

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo Yes. The macro register would contain something like this for example: `/NullPointerException/<CR>kd/omitted/+0<CR>`, so search for NPE, go up one line, linewise-delete until "omitted". But recording this takes some time and I asked myself whether this can't be performed faster.

Comment: Not sure I completely get it but doesn't following suffice: `g/whatever/,/matchEndOfBlock/d`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the answers here, I was able to code a very handy function: The sources below enables one to select text and remove all lines with the same (or similar) text in the current buffer. That works with both in-line and multiline selection. As I said I was searching for something that made me faster in analyzing log files. Log files typically contain dates and times and these change all the time, so it's a good idea to have something that let's us ignore numbers. Let's see. I'm using these two mappings:

```
vnoremap d :<C-U>echo RemoveSelectionFromBuffer(0)<CR>
vnoremap D :<C-U>echo RemoveSelectionFromBuffer(1)<CR>
```

Typical usage:

- Remove similar lines ignoring numbers: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>
- Remove same matches (single line): Mark text inline (leaving out dates and times), then <kbd>d</kbd>
- Remove same matches (multiline): Mark text across lines (leaving out dates and times), then <kbd>d</kbd>

Here's the source code:

```
" Removes lines matching the selected text from buffer.
function! RemoveSelectionFromBuffer(ignoreNumbers)
    let lines = GetVisualSelection() " selected lines
    " Escape backslashes and slashes (delimiters)
    call map(lines, {k, v -> substitute(v, '\\\|/', '\\&', 'g')})
    if a:ignoreNumbers == 1
        " Substitute all numbers with \s*\d\s* - in formatted output matching
        " lines may have whitespace instead of numbers. All backslashes need
        " to be escaped because \V (very nomagic) will be used.
        call map(lines, {k, v -> substitute(v, '\s*\d\+\s*', '\\s\\*\\d\\+\\s\\*', 'g')})
    endif
    let blc = line('$') " number of lines in buffer (before deletion)
    let vlc = len(lines) " number of selected lines
    let pattern = join(lines, '\_.') " support multiline patterns
    let cmd = ':g/\V' . pattern . '/d_' . vlc " delete matching lines (d_3)
    let pos = getpos('v') " save position
    execute "silent " . cmd
    call setpos('.', pos) " restore position
    let dlc = blc - line('$') " number of deleted lines
    let dmc = dlc / vlc " number of deleted matches
    let cmd = substitute(cmd, '\(.\{50\}\).*', '\1...', '') " command output
    let lout = dlc . ' line' . (dlc == 1 ? '' : 's')
    let mout = '(' . dmc . ' match' . (dmc == 1 ? '' : 'es') . ')'
    return printf('%s removed: %s', (vlc == 1 ? lout : lout . ' ' . mout), cmd)
endfunction
```

I took the `GetVisualSelection()` code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47051271/845034).

```
function! GetVisualSelection()
    if mode() == "v"
        let [line_start, column_start] = getpos("v")[1:2]
        let [line_end, column_end] = getpos(".")[1:2]
    else
        let [line_start, column_start] = getpos("'<")[1:2]
        let [line_end, column_end] = getpos("'>")[1:2]
    end
    if (line2byte(line_start)+column_start) > (line2byte(line_end)+column_end)
        let [line_start, column_start, line_end, column_end] =
        \   [line_end, column_end, line_start, column_start]
    end
    let lines = getline(line_start, line_end)
    if len(lines) == 0
            return ''
    endif
    let lines[-1] = lines[-1][: column_end - 1]
    let lines[0] = lines[0][column_start - 1:]
    return lines
endfunction
```

Thanks, aepksbuck, DoktorOSwaldo and Kent.

Answer (score 4):

If I  understood your problem right, this command should do what you want:

```
:g/NullPointer/,/omitt/d
```

Example:

### Before:

```
1
2
3
NullPointerException1
4
5
6
omitted
7
NullPointerException2
8
9
omitted
10
```

### After:

```
1
2
3
7
10
```

Please read `:h edit-paragraph-join`, there is good explanation for the command, your case is just changing `join` into `d`

Comment: And in order to remove also the line before expr: `:g/NullPointer/-1,/omitt/d`. Thanks, that works quite well!

Answer (score 2):

```
:g/whatever/d2
```

will delete a line with `whatever` and the line after it. If you can find text that always happens in the first line, you can strip out all of the following text if it has the same number of lines by changing `2` to whatever you need.

Comment: Yes, but this ignores two facts: (1) »Go to start anchor« and (2) I think, I can get more effective by mapping this to a key in visual mode in order to remove single or multiple lines that contain the selected text. Oh, and for (1) `:g/whatever/.-1d` could be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You could actually just use some normal commands in a global command to achieve what you want, look at your example (hope i understood it more or less right):

```
someText
NullPointerException
...
omitted
```

you want to delte from the line above `NPE` until the line with `omitted` right?
Just use the following:

```
:g/NullPointerException/execute "normal! kddd/omitted\<cr>dd"
```

It maybe looks complex, but it isn't. It is not better than a macro<sup>1</sup>
, but i like commands more, because I always make errors recording macros.

Since it only uses normal vim movements, it is easy to adopt. If you f.e. not know where your previous anchor is, you could use `?anchor\<cr>` instead of `kd`. For a better demonstration you will have to submit a realistic example.

<sup>[1] You could argue, that this only needs to be run once, but that is also true for a recursive macro http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Record_a_recursive_macro</sup>

Comment: Thanks. That's a bit easier than reparing a macro (`"qp` and `"qy$`). And the initialization phase of a recursive macro is fast (instead of e. g. `10000000@q` - try that on an empty text file, it takes a couple of seconds or even minutes).