# vim fzf get selected word as --query parameter

Tags: vim, fzf

I'm actually searching to make fuzzy search with `:FZF` in vim, but with parameter like this `:FZF -q /tmp/boulou`

But, replace the `/tmp/boulou` by the words selected in the visual mode and bind it to a vmap.

Have you got an idea to help me ?

Thanks, kind regards

Comment: How far have you come? do you already have a function which takes a range as argument? do you have a `vmap` yet? do you know how to call `fzf` in vimscript? What do you want to do if more than a line is selected? what to do in visual block mode?

Comment: this work in command: `:FZF -q /tmp/boulou`, nop, i do not have a function for this, my vmap is like this `vnoremap <leader>f :FZF -q <C-r><cr>`, and i just want to select a line

Comment: At the moment you are selecting the word under the cursor for the search,   not the line. So it is correct that you always, want to search the whole line? or just the selected words?

Comment: Just the selected word, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Ok, you should narrow the question down to some partial steps. I don't think anybody is going to write it all for you. 1. Create a function in your `.vimrc` which takes a range as argument. 2. create a `vmap` to call the function. 3. extract the selected text in your function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533565/how-to-get-visually-selected-text-in-vimscript. 4. feed the thex to fzf https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/wiki/Examples-(vim). This should all be more or less solvable with SO. Once you have specific questions I will gladly help you again.

Comment: Thanks i'll try with your explaination :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Accordingly to xolox [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533565/how-to-get-visually-selected-text-in-vimscript/6271254#6271254), you can create mapping like this:

```
function! s:getVisualSelection()
    let [line_start, column_start] = getpos("'<")[1:2]
    let [line_end, column_end] = getpos("'>")[1:2]
    let lines = getline(line_start, line_end)

    if len(lines) == 0
        return ""
    endif

    let lines[-1] = lines[-1][:column_end - (&selection == "inclusive" ? 1 : 2)]
    let lines[0] = lines[0][column_start - 1:]

    return join(lines, "\n")
endfunction

vnoremap <silent><leader>f <Esc>:FZF -q <C-R>=<SID>getVisualSelection()<CR><CR>
```

Keep in mind, it will work only for word selection. It will not work for multilines or selection which contains tab characters. You just need to call a function instead of a command but since I do not have fzf installed you have to do this by yourself.

In case you need to search the word under the cursor (in normal mode):

```
nnoremap <silent><leader>f :FZF -q <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
```