# Is there a way to get the rightmost column of a visual block selection?

Tags: vim

Assume that `virtualedit=`. Consider the following text file.

```
1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 3 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 4 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 7 1 1 1
```

If I visual-block-select lines 2 through 4 and use `$` to make the selection non-rectangular, the following code will fail to find the rightmost column in the selection. More explicitly, I use the key sequence `2G^vjj$`, where `^v` is Control-V.

```
" rightmostCol becomes 15, not 19 as desired.
let rightmostCol = virtcol("'>")
```

**Is there some other function I can call, or expression I can pass to `virtcol`, to programmatically get the column number of the rightmost column in my Visual Block selection?**

Note that simply finding the length of the longest line in the visual block is incorrect, because the visual selection could have also been rectangular, and those cases should not be treated the same way.

**Edit**: If it was possible to determine whether the visual block selection is rectangular or not, that would also work.

Comment: didn't understand your last paragraph. you go through the visual selection lines, and find the longest line. why it won't work? and what do you really want?  why you do a block selection in this case?

Comment: Perhaps, this is stupid, but you can do `ygv` and then inspect the contents of the register.

Comment: Related: [How to get visually selected text in VimScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533565/how-to-get-visually-selected-text-in-vimscript)

Comment: @Kent, It's a block selection because I am writing a plugin to drag text around and care about whether the user actually selected a rectangular block (in which case I can identify the rectangle of text by looking only at the (line, column) tuples of the beginning and ending marks), or a non-rectangular block (in which case I want to pretend it's a rectangle anyways, but the rightmost edge is defined by the rightmost selected column, not the column at the ending mark.)

Comment: @Kent, The two cases reduce to the same case of finding the rightmost visually selected column in visual block mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way to distinguish those cases through marks. One solution would be to analyze the text yourself, adding the longest line length to the leftmost visual mark position. It is important to check both marks since they could be reversed in case the selection was made towards the start.

```
function! RightmostVirtualColumn()
    let reg_v = @v
    silent normal! gv"vy
    let max = 0
    for line in split(getreg('v'), '\n')
        let len = strlen(line)
        let max = max([len, max])
    endfor
    let @v = reg_v
    let max += min([virtcol("'<"), virtcol("'>")]) - 1
    return max
endfunction
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a VimScript function:

```
function! GetRightmostCol()
   let start=line("'<")
   let end=line("'>")
   let line=start
   let len=len(getline(line))
   while line<=end
      let len=len<len(getline(line))?len(getline(line)):len
      let line+=1
   endwhile
   return len
endfunction
```

Alternatively approach using register 0:

```
function! GetRightmostCol()
   let lines=split(getreg(0),"\n")
   let len=0
   for line in lines
      let len=len<len(line)?len(line):len
      let line+=1
   endfor
   return len
endfunction
```

Then use the function in the assignment:

```
:let rightmostCol = GetRightmostCol()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I think this only works if you assume the user used `C-v$`. But the user might not have done that.

Comment: I had forgotten the `return len` line, now it works with any visual selection

Comment: It seems that this grabs the rightmost column *in the lines that have any columns selected*, not the rightmost column *that is itself selected*. For example, in my example, if I just select the first column of every row, then the desired output is 1, but this function will return 19.

Comment: Then you could yank the visual selection and use register 0 to get the rightmost column (see update)

Comment: That does not give the rightmost column; it gives the length of the longest line of the selection. If the selection starts at column 3, then it will give a number that is too small by 2.